# react-bootstrap simple installation on meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am going to start react-bootstrap. 
There are many git sources for react-bootstrap on github, but I couldn't run them successfully. 
I want to use windows and ubuntu for development. 
And I prefer meteor for this working.
I would like to know simple way to easy installation and git url for very simple react-bootstrap examples. 
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This one is up to date and widely used:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/

Type the following on your command line and you're good to go:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```